# How to get "phi" instruction in llvm without optimization

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

When I use the command `clang -emit-llvm -S test.c -o test.ll`, there is no any "phi" instruction in the IR file. How can I get it?

I know that I can use the pass "-mem2reg" or "-gvn" to get "phi" instruction. But they would do some optimization. I just want to get "phi" without any optimization.

Comment: mem2reg (aka PromotePass) does not depend on any other passes except DominatorTree analysis, which, obviously, does not change the IR.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure what you mean by "do some optimization" but it seems to me that `mem2reg` is *exactly* what you need. Here is how it's [described in the documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#mem2reg-promote-memory-to-register):

> This file promotes memory references to be register references. It
>   promotes alloca instructions which only have loads and stores as uses.
>   An alloca is transformed by using dominator frontiers to place phi
>   nodes, then traversing the function in depth-first order to rewrite
>   loads and stores as appropriate. This is just the standard SSA
>   construction algorithm to construct “pruned” SSA form.

Clang itself does not produce optimized LLVM IR. It produces fairly straightforward IR wherein locals are kept in memory (using `alloca`s). The optimizations are done by `opt` on LLVM IR level, and one of the most important optimizations is indeed `mem2reg` which makes sure that locals are represented in LLVM's SSA values instead of memory.